# Why gas fee on Uniswap is far far higher than normal gas fee

Tags: gas-price, uniswapv3

The transaction fee for swapping tokens on Uniswap is significantly higher than the normal Ethereum transaction fee. I wonder why?

Note: You can obtain real-time gas fees from https://etherscan.io/gastracker. Additionally, you can also view the gas fees for Uniswap V3.

Answer (score 2):

Are you comparing the gas of doing a swap on Uniswap compared to, say, the gas cost to send Ether from one wallet to another? Because a lot more computations go into performing a swap than doing a transfer of ether. That's why you will see higher fees on all DeFi protocols compared to the cost to transfer ether or tokens.

That being said, I think a lot of devs do not always make the effort to keep gas as low as it could be. Aave gas costs are so high! I refuse to believe they couldn't have made at least some gas optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum transaction costs are measured by how much they use [Ethereum Virtual Machine](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/evm) resources. This includes storing data in the blockchain, using network bandwidth, and calculating stuff on the CPU. More complex transactions cost more.

- Gas price unit is the same for all the transactions in the same block (gas/eth) and a function of block space demand (usage of the blockchain at the moment)
- Unit of gas a transaction consumes varies by the complexity of a transaction

Because Uniswap transactions are more complex than sending Ethereum transactions, they cost more.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum operates on a "first-price auction" mechanism for transactions. Users set their own gas prices (in Gwei) when sending transactions. Miners tend to prioritize transactions with higher gas prices because it means higher rewards for them. If many users are willing to pay higher fees, the overall gas fees on the network will increase.This may be the main reason, I think.

Comment: No, you don't get the main point of my question. Take an example, for the time being, the current average ETH gas fee is $0.99 USD equivalent, whereas on Uniswap V3, it is $8.74 USD, nearly nine times higher. I am curious why the gas fee on Uniswap is considerably higher than the usual average.

Comment: 1. Uniswap holds the distinction of being the largest decentralized exchange (DEX) on the Ethereum blockchain. On-chain Execution can lead to increased Gas fees due to the demand for transactions. Since there is often a direct financial incentive for users to execute trades quickly, many DEX users are willing to pay higher Gas fees.

Comment: 2. In Uniswap V3, prior to the execution of a transaction, ETH is wrapped into WETH (Wrapped Ether). This wrapping process incurs additional transfer costs compared to using native ETH, resulting in extra Gas fees. 3. Uniswap V3 imposes a high Gas Limit when completing various operations such as executing transactions, providing liquidity, and deleting liquidity. This is because these activities can be complex and require more computational resources, leading to higher Gas costs. Hoping these will help you.

Answer (score 0):

AMMs pose challenges to traditional SPOT DEX platforms due to their one-to-one trading approach and inherent drawbacks:

Slow Transactions: AMMs have longer transaction times due to one-to-one trading.

Lack of Price Visibility: Users can't see prices or control slippage before trading.

Capital-Intensive Pools: Creating pools requires significant capital, attracting more hackers and increasing risks.

Security Concerns with Growth: Larger pools become vulnerable to security issues, especially if there are bugs from the start.

Inflexible Bug Corrections: AMMs struggle to address bugs swiftly as the user base expands.

The industry may not have adopted Central Limit Order Books (CLOBs) as an AMM replacement, possibly due to the advantages of traditional order books in transparency, slippage control, and real-time price visibility. Exploring CLOBs further could offer solutions to AMM challenges.

Answer (score -1):

Centralized Exchanges (CEXs) operate by maintaining order books, which are lists of buy and sell orders for various assets. These order books are crucial for matching buyers and sellers at agreed-upon prices. However, when implemented in a Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) like PostgreSQL, the decentralization aspect of CEXs can be compromised. This is because the order books are stored and managed in a centralized database, which can lead to a single point of failure and potential vulnerabilities to hacking 1.

Decentralized Exchanges (DEXs), on the other hand, aim to eliminate the need for a centralized authority by utilizing Automated Market Makers (AMMs). AMMs, such as those implemented by Uniswap, use smart contracts on the blockchain to automatically execute trades without the need for a centralized market maker. This approach is more gas-efficient and can significantly reduce the costs associated with maintaining large order books on the blockchain, which can be very expensive 12.

dYdX is an example of a DEX that operates in a middle ground. It maintains order books but also carries out operations over the blockchain. This hybrid approach allows dYdX to offer a balance between the efficiency of AMMs and the decentralization of order book-based DEXs. By doing so, dYdX aims to provide a more flexible and cost-effective trading platform 1.

In summary, while CEXs use order books to facilitate trading, the decentralization of these order books in RDBMS can compromise the decentralized nature of the exchange. DEXs, particularly those using AMMs like Uniswap, offer a more gas-efficient and decentralized alternative. dYdX represents a hybrid approach, combining the benefits of both order book-based and AMM-based DEXs to provide a flexible and efficient trading platform.

Comment: Please avoid copy-pasting AI responses.

Comment: Its not Ai response, just have  AI autocomplete assist extension